# Can I replace jni .so file in android apk

Tags: java-native-interface, shared-libraries, apk

I want to upgrade my Bluetooth.apk's linked bluedroid stack. Since I am using it in Android watch, google has not provide source code for it.
I only want to recompile thouse bluedroid stack with new code, then use the original app to link it.
Is it possiblfe? It seems the apk can not find those some interface, any suggestions?

Android wear only open part of its code, I only recompiled source from AOSP, which seems near the release version, I think its base component like bluestack is opened.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, native libraries link against specific symbols from a library. If the library changes significantly (which I presume, otherwise you wouldn't want to update), it does no longer contain exactly the same symbols. You'd have to repeat the linking process.

However, for that you'd need the original binary with unresolved symbols, which usually only exists as an intermediate product in the build process. If you don't have the source, it's unlikely you'll get that.

I wouldn't be sure however that you can't get the source for whatever core component you need -- Android as is is open source, and there's no reason why a bluetooth stack based on it wouldn't.